# Azure pipeline not running NUnit tests

Tags: c#, azure

Just been introduced to Azure piplelines. My project is a .NET project and is linked up with Azure but does not run my Unit Tests before integrating (therefore is integrating everything even with failing tests)

My .yaml file is:

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

My unit tests are in the solution under a project called `MyProjectTests` and in a file called `ProjectTests.cs`. Can anyone please advise what I need to add to my yaml file (or do in general?) to get these to run please? I have looked into this myself and can't seem to find a solution and I want to avoid clogging up my commit history with failed attempts to run the unit tests.

Thanks so much.

UPDATE:

I have fixed by adding the following:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: You're only doing a build here, there's no step to run tests.

Comment: Hi @davidG yes I know - I want to add a step to run tests but am not sure of the correct syntax ?

Comment: Well, you could just do the same as you have for the `build` but use `test` instead.

Comment: The easiest way to generate example yaml files is to get Azure DevOps to do it for you. Use the UI to create a basic pipeline with a test and examine the yam lit gives you.

Comment: @davidG So something like

`script: dotnet test --configuration $(buildConfiguration)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: 'PathToTestProject/TestProject.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Debug'
```

You can choose whatever configuration you like, of course. And the displayName is optional. If any of your tests fail, the Pipeline will abort subsequent steps.

Comment: Thanks so much @RobReagan very helpful of you. I am receiving this error though: `Unexpected value 'task'"` and the build fails?

Comment: and unexpected value for displayName and inputs as well :(

Comment: @juemura7 Oops, I forgot the hyphen. I have added it to the answer. Can you mark as the answer for other folks who may wonder across this thread in the future? Thanks!

Comment: thanks Rob! It actually didn't work though - I used another solution and updated my original post :)